# Canon LBP 2900b is not Working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing

I have the new Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed my printer(Canon LBP2900b) in Ubuntu. While printing it shows printing the page, after some time it shows printing completed.But, my printer does not responding. By checking the printer state, it shows "Idle - ccp send_data error, exit"

Comment: Have you installed all the drivers?

Comment: Yes, I think. If not so, how can I check it.

Comment: Try the answer provided below. It should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

First install the latest drivers.
For **Canon LBP 2900B** - https://in.canon/en/support/0100459601/7?model=0017B011

**Download and extract**

[image]

Now based on your OS( 32-bit or 64-bit) install the Debian packages

[image]